# Call ToJson Method For T Class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm new on Dart & Flutter. I have to post data to internet.

I would to use a common class method for this.
In other hand i need to convert my object to JSON.
But how can do it with T class or is there other elegant way?

Could you give me an opinion?

```
Future<ReturnModel> postData<T>(T model) async {
  final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://localhost/SomeAddress'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },

      //**
      IDE gives error here of course. 
      Because it is not know type of T.
      How can i get over this?
      **//
      body: jsonEncode(model.toJson())
  );

  if (response.statusCode == StatusCode.OK) {
    return ReturnModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Bir hata oluştu.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body: jsonEncode(((model) as dynamic).toJson())
```